# In Orchard, how to query based on current user's content picker field?

Tags: orchardcms

I have extended the built-in `User` **ContentType** with a Content Picker Field that can be used to select multiple `Video` **ContentItems**. This gives me a video multi-picker control on the Edit page of each `User`.

[image: Multi Picker on User Edit screen]

I love how Orchard CMS makes this so elegantly simple to setup.

Now that I can associate multiple `Videos` with a `User`, I'd like to create a **Query** that will display just the `Videos` that the currently logged in `User` has been granted access.

I was hoping to be able to setup a **Query** using the Projector module, in what I thought was the obvious way (see below), but this returns no results.

[image: Query definition]

This is how I configured the second filter:

1. Clicked on the `+ Add a new Filter` link on the Edit Query screen
2. Chose `Videos:Ids` from the `User Content Fields` section, like this:
   [image: Videos:Ids filter option]
3. Configured the new filter like this:
   [image: Filter settings]

What am I doing wrong, or what is the simplest way of diagnosing this issue?

This is how the Content Picker field is defined:

[image: Content Picker Field definition]

Comment: Can you explain what the second filter is and how you configured it?

Comment: Many thanks for responding @BertrandLeRoy. I have added the requested info to the question

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted my error - it was due to me not having a proper understand of how the filters worked. The `Videos:Ids` filter in the `User Content Fields` section does not give access to the *current user's* list of videos, as I assumed. Instead, it is offering the field to be used in the filter, which would be useful if I were to write a query to produce a list of `Users` that had access to a specific Video.

It was wishful thinking that it worked the way I wanted, but it's obvious in retrospect how it actually works.

**Update**: in the hope it's useful for others, here's the custom filter I developed:

```
public interface IFilterProvider : IEventHandler
{
    void Describe(dynamic describe);
}

public class CurrentUserVideosFilter : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _workContextAccessor;

    public CurrentUserVideosFilter(IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor)
    {
        _workContextAccessor = workContextAccessor;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public void Describe(dynamic describe)
    {
        describe.For("My Filter Category", T("My Filter Category"), T("My Filter Category"))
            .Element("Current User's Videos", T("Current User's Videos"), T("Current User's Videos"),
                (Action<dynamic>)ApplyFilter,
                (Func<dynamic, LocalizedString>)DisplayFilter,
                null
            );
    }

    public void ApplyFilter(dynamic context)
    {
        var query = (IHqlQuery)context.Query;

        context.Query = query.ForType("Video")
            .Where(x => x.ContentPartRecord<IdentityPartRecord>(), x => x.InG("Id", GetVideoIdsForCurrentUser()));
    }

    private IList<int> GetVideoIdsForCurrentUser()
    {
        var currentUser = _workContextAccessor.GetContext().CurrentUser;

        if (currentUser == null) return new int[0];

        dynamic item = currentUser.ContentItem;
        var videoContentItems = (IEnumerable<ContentItem>)item.User.Videos.ContentItems;

        return videoContentItems.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
    }

    public LocalizedString DisplayFilter(dynamic context)
    {
        return T("Videos that have been assigned to the currently logged in user");
    }
}
```

I created this class in a new Orchard module, which contains all my customisations for the site I'm building. Once I installed the module, the filter was immediately available. I assume Orchard uses reflection to seek out all types that implement the `IFilterProvider` interface.

This is how the filter appears on the `Add a Filter` screen:

[image: Custom filter as it appears on the "Add a Filter" screen]

Clicking on the filter shows this screen:

[image: Edit details of the custom filter]

Once the filter has been saved, the query works exactly how I'd like - it shows all videos that have been assigned to the currently logged in user.

Comment: Yo may have to write your own filter. Use existing ones as examples.

Comment: I followed one of the other examples, as you suggested, and I now have a working solution (see above). Thanks for your help @BertrandLeRoy

Comment: Do a search for NogginBox.OwnerQueries (either GitHub or the Orchard Gallery). This creates a filter for "Content Owner" with choices for Author of current content (owned by author of page's main document, works best with widgets), Specified user (Is owned by the specified user) and Logged in user (Is owned by logged in user). This is very general and avoids the need of creating a custom module for every instance you need. I understand @Wheelie that you had specific requirements. Whereas you wrapped your requirements in one filter (videos + user), module requires two filters. HTH.